# Subprocess.run security risk when opening an external application?

Tags: windows, security, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

I've been reading about possible security risks when using "shell=true" with subprocess.run - re a user having the ability to run arbitary code. Does this still apply if I'm opening an external application using subprocess.run ? In my case a PDF viewer.

The code I'm using is:

```
self.outputbox.tag_bind("dwg", "<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, filename=path + '/' + linkname: subprocess.run(filename, shell=True))
```

Where the 'filename' is created from a hardcoded variables "path","linkname"

I can get the file to open correctly when using shell=True, when this is removed various errors pop up in idle shell. I'm a bit worried that I could be opening myself up for problems, hence my question

Comment: If either `path` or `linkname` is from user input, then it's potentially a problem. In this case it's avoidable. The cmd shell opens a PDF by calling `ShellExecuteEx`. You can get the same result via `os.startfile(filename)`, which calls `ShellExecute`. This is a bit safer than using cmd since the Windows `ShellExecute` function has a constrained interface that requires specifying the operation, file, and parameters separately. `os.startfile` allows passing the file and optional operation, but not parameters.

Comment: @eryksun thank you for the reply - good information. My program allows for no user input apart from clicking a link in a text widget which in turn  opens a pdf (based on a fixed path location and the above linkname rule for creating the file reference). So it looks like I should be all good. Will bare this in mind for the future, cheers :)